# How to have Microsoft Read Aloud read alternative text

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am using Read Aloud for my online course and it is not reading some words properly.  For instance, when reading the text n:g=n:g, Read Aloud reads "n g equals n g" where we would prefer it read "n to g equal n to g".  I have tried using aria properties such as

```
<span aria-label="n to g equals n to g"><span aria-hidden="true">n:g=n:g</span></span>
```

but with no success.  I know an appropriate screen reader, such as JAWS, would be more appropriate, we are required to have our clients use Read Aloud because it does not require them to download or purchase addition programs.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make some tests and find that Edge Read Aloud won't read `aria-label`. I think that's by design, and we can't change it by code. You can provide feedback about this issue to Edge team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I** in Edge.

As a workaround, you can use the free screenreader [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/). I've tested and it can read the value in `aria-label`. Besides, if you want the `aria-label` to be read, you'll have to add the [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions) attribute to the `<span>`. You can also refer to [this doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support) and [this blog](https://www.tpgi.com/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/) for detailed information about ARIA guidelines.